# Having a problem with an error. How do I get rid of (index):479 Uncaught ReferenceError: grabText is not defined?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, function

```
    <style>
 .column {
float: left;
width: 50%;
padding: 10px;
}
/* Clear floats after the columns *
.row:after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
}
/* Container holding the image and the text */
.container {
position: relative;
}
/* Centered text */
.centered {
text-shadow: 0 0 2px, 0 0 5px, 0 0 50px, 0 0 10px, 0 0 60px, 0 0 60px;
position: absolute;
top: 30%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
color: white;
}
</style>
<h1>DESIGN YOUR OWN VIBE</h1>
<h3>Type in your message, choose font, and color.</h3>
<div class="column">
<div class="container">
<img style="box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black;" src="https://omgneonsigns.com/wp-content/plugins/neon-designer-1.5.4/includes/image/background1.jpg" />
<div class="centered">
<p id="text" style="font-size: 45px; padding-right: 10px;"></p>
</div>
</div>
<h1>Total Cost:<span id="outputCost" style="font-size: 25px; padding-right: 10px;"></span></h1>
</div>
<div class="column" style="box-shadow: 5px 2px 55px gray;">
<h3>INPUT TEXT</h3>
<form action="/cart/?add-to-cart=5825" method="post" name="contentForm">
<p id="remainingChars"></p>
<textarea id="enteredText" style="height: 15px;" name="enteredText" onkeyup="grabText()" onkeydown="countChars(this)" placeholder="Your Text..."></textarea>
<input id="hiddenText" name="hiddenText" type="hidden" value=""></input>
<h3>CHOOSE FONT</h3>
<select name="chosenFont" onchange="changeFontStyle(this)">
<option value="select">-SELECT-</option>
<option style="font-family: 'roboto';" value="roboto">Roboto</option>
<option style="font-family: 'arial';" value="arial">Arial</option>
<option style="font-family: 'times new roman';" value="times new roman">Times New Roman</option>
<option style="font-family: 'comic sans ms';" value="comic sans ms">Comic Sans MS</option>
<option style="font-family: 'clarendon-fortune-bold';" value="clarendon fortune bold">Clarendon Fortune</option>
<option style="font-family: 'copperplate';" value="copperplate">Copperplate</option>
<option style="font-family: 'ribbon-condensed';" value="ribbon condensed">Ribbon Condensed</option>
</select>
<input id="hiddenFont" name="hiddenFont" type="hidden" value=""></input>
<h3>CHOOSE COLOR</h3>
<select id="selectedColor" name="chosenColor" onchange="changeColorStyle(this)">
<option value="select">-SELECT-</option>
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
<option value="green">Green</option>
<option value="orange">Orange</option>
<option value="pink">Pink</option>
<option value="white">White</option>
<option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
<option value="#dce6ef">Ice Blue</option>
</select>
<input id="hiddenColor" name="hiddenColor" type="hidden" value="" />
<h3>CHOOSE SIZE</h3>
<select id="selectedSize" name="chosenSize" onchange="getTotal();">
<option value="select">-SELECT-</option>
<option value="20">20"</option>
<option value="30">30"</option>
<option value="40">40"</option>
<option value="50">50"</option>
<option value="60">60"</option>
</select>
<input id="hiddenSize" name="hiddenSize" type="hidden" value="" />
<h3>CHOOSE POWER WIRE</h3>
Power wire on back is recommended for professional installation by an electrician. Power wire on front is recommended for residential installation.
<select id="selectedPowerWire" name="chosenPower" onchange="getTotal();">
<option value="select">-SELECT-</option>
<option value="front">Power Wire In FRONT</option>
<option value="back">Power Wire In BACK</option>
</select>
<input id="hiddenPowerWire" name="hiddenPowerWire" type="hidden" value="" />
<h3>CHOOSE MOUNT</h3>
Wall mount is recommended for general installations. Hanging is recommended for window display.
<select id="selectedMount" name="chosenMount" onchange="getTotal();">
<option value="select">-SELECT-</option>
<option value="wall mount">Wall Mount</option>
<option value="hanging">Hanging</option>
<option value="stand">Stand</option>
</select>
<input id="hiddenMount" name="hiddenMount" type="hidden" value="" />
<h3>CHOOSE BACKING</h3>
<select id="selectedBacking" name="chosenBacking" onchange="getTotal();">
<option value="select">-SELECT-</option>
<option value="cut to shape">Cut To Shape</option>
<option value="whole board">Whole Board</option>
</select>
<input id="hiddenBacking" name="hiddenBacking" type="hidden" value="" />
<h3>DIMMER?</h3>
<select id="selectedDimmer" name="chosenDimmer" onchange="getTotal();">
<option value="select">-SELECT-</option>
<option value="yes">Yes ($50.00)</option>
<option value="no">No</option>
</select>
<input id="hiddenDimmer" name="hiddenDimmer" type="hidden" value="" />
<input id="price" name="price" type="hidden" value="" />
<input id="hiddenChars" name="hiddenChars" type="hidden" value="" />
<input type="submit" id="submitValues" value="Add To Cart" />
</form></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function grabText() {
  var x = document.getElementById("enteredText").value;
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = x;
getTotal();
});
var changeFontStyle = function (font) {
          document.getElementById(
                "text").style.fontFamily
                        = font.value;
};
var changeColorStyle = function (color) {
    document.getElementById("text").style.color = color.value;
};
$(document).ready(function countChars(obj){
    var maxLength = 20;
    var strLength = obj.value.length + 1;
    var charRemain = (maxLength - strLength);
    document.getElementById("hiddenChars").value = strLength;
    if(charRemain < 0){
        document.getElementById("remainingChars").innerHTML = '<span style="color: red;">You have exceeded the limit of '+maxLength+' characters</span>';
    }else{
        document.getElementById("remainingChars").innerHTML = charRemain+' characters remaining';
    }
});
$(document).ready(function getTotal() {
  var z = document.getElementById("hiddenChars").value;
  var x = document.getElementById("selectedSize").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("selectedMount").value;
  var d = document.getElementById("selectedDimmer").value;
if(x != "select" && z === "") {
  document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' Please enter custom text.';
  document.getElementById("price").value = NULL;
  document.getElementById("submitValues").disabled = true;
}
if(x === "20" && z === "1") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $180';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("180.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "1") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $263';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("263.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "1") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $306';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("306.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "1") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $330';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("330.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "1") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $380';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("380.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "2") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $200';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("200.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "2") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $286';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("286.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "2") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $332';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("332.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "2") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $360';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("360.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "2") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $410';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("410.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "3") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $220';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("220.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "3") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $309';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("309.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "3") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $358';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("358.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "3") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $480';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("480.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "3") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $440';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("440.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "4") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $240';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("240.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "4") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $332';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("332.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "4") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $384';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("384.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "4") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $580';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("580.00");
 }   
if(x === "60" && z === "4") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $470';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("470.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "5") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $260';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("260.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "5") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $355';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("355.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "5") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $410';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("410.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "5") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $458';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("458.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "5") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $500';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("500.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "6") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $280';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("280.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "6") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $378';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("378.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "6") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $436';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("436.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "6") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $558';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("558.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "6") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $530';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("530.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "7") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $300';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("300.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "7") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $401';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("401.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "7") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $462';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("462.00");
 }  
if(x === "50" && z === "7") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $436';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("436.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "7") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $560';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("560.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "8") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $320';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("320.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "8") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $424';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("424.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "8") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $488';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("488.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "8") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $536';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("536.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "8") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $590';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("590.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "9") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $340';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("340.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "9") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $447';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("447.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "9") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $514';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("514.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "9") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $636';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("636.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "9") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $620';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("620.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "10") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $360';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("360.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "10") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $470';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("470.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "10") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $540';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("540.00");'
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "10") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $510';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("510.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "10") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $650';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("650.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "11") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $380';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("380.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "11") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $493';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("493.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "11") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $566';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("566.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "11") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $610';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("610.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "11") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $680';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("680.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "12") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $400';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("400.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "12") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $516';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("516.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "12") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $592';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("592.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "12") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $710';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("710.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "12") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $710';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("710.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "13") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $420';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("420.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "13") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $539';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("539.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "13") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $618';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("618.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "13") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $570';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("570.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "13") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $740';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("740.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "14") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $440';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("440.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "14") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $562';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("562.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "14") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $644';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("644.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "14") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $670';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("670.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "14") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $770';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("770.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "15") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $460';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("460.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "15") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $585';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("585.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "15") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $670';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("670.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "15") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $770';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("770.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "15") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $800';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("800.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "16") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $480';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("480.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "16") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $608';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("608.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "16") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $696';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("696.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "16") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $800';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("800.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "16") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $830';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("830.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "17") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $500';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("500.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "17") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $631';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("631.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "17") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $722';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("722.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "17") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $800';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("800.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "17") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $860';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("860.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "18") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $520';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("520.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "18") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $654';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("654.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "18") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $748';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("748.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "18") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $800';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("800.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "18") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $890';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("890.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "19") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $540';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("540.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "19") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $677';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("677.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "19") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $774';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("774.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "19") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $800';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("800.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "19") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $920';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("920.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "20") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $560';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("560.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "20") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $700';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("800.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "20") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $800';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("800.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "20") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $800';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("800.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "20") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $950';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("950.00");
 }
if(d === "yes") {
 var p = document.getElementById("price").value;
 console.log(p);
 var n = parseFloat("50.00");
 console.log(n);
 t = +p + +n;
 console.log(t);
 document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = " $" + t;
 }
});
function getOption() { 
    selectElement = document.querySelector('#selectedFont');                     
    output = selectElement.value; 
    document.querySelector('.output').textContent = output;
getTotal();
}; 
function getSizeOption() { 
    selectElement = document.querySelector('#selectedSize');                  
    outputSize = selectElement.value;   
    document.querySelector('.outputSize').textContent = outputSize;     
    getTotal(); 
};
function getMountOption() { 
    selectElement = document.querySelector('#selectedMount');                      
    outputMount = selectElement.value;  
    document.querySelector('.outputMount').textContent = outputMount;   
    getTotal();
};  
function getPowerWireOption() { 
    selectElement = document.querySelector('#selectedPowerWire');                   
    outputPowerWire = selectElement.value;
    document.querySelector('.outputPowerWire').textContent = outputPowerWire;   
    getTotal();
}; 
function getBackingOption() { 
    selectElement = document.querySelector('#selectedBacking');                
    outputBacking = selectElement.value;  
    document.querySelector('.outputBacking').textContent = outputBacking; 
    getTotal();
};
function getColorOption() { 
    selectElement = document.querySelector('#selectedColor'); 
    outputColor = selectElement.value; 
    document.querySelector('.outputColor').textContent = outputColor; 
getTotal();
}; 
</script>
```

Sorry it's long, but here the code I am working with. The weird part about this is that when I add new functions, they seem to work just fine... and then when I go to EDIT those and new some new code to the function, I get this error.

I am not really sure what's wrong with the code. I am making sure to only load the function(s) giving errors AFTER DOM, and it's still giving me issues.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Here's the full error:

```
(index):479 Uncaught ReferenceError: grabText is not defined
    at HTMLTextAreaElement.onkeyup ((index):479)
```

Comment: you don't need to define functions in document.ready

Comment: @Nikki9696 Yeah, although I was hoping that by telling it to wait for the DOM it would fix the problem... to no avail. Even if I remove that from my functions, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Dev console is your best friend - that's how I found your extra single quote. It doesn't like those.

Comment: @Nikki9696 Thanks for doing that. I removed the extra single quote, and have removed the document.ready and I am still experiencing the problem. The weird part is that it doesn't do it, every time! Only at certain times!

Comment: Can you try narrowing down "certain times" - might it have to do with browser caching? How are you editing (inline? text document and then save?), and when do you get the error (like when you try to refresh the page? after deploying it somewhere?) Also, put the script in HEAD instead of inline in the body, see if that helps. Most of the time, the functions would be in a js file that's included in head.

Comment: @Nikki9696 Yes. I am editing it in the wordpress "text" editor (for lack of better options). I can add a function, and its perfectly happy, but then when I go to either add another function, or edit an existing one, I get the error. 

I have tried testing all of my fields with event functions, and they ALL throw that same error, no matter what I do. It just seems really strange that only certain things trigger it.

Comment: @Nikki9696 I ran the snippet that you posted below, and it runs just fine here. I'm not sure why in wordpress that would be any different...?

Comment: Ah, so you're limited. I'd say try to put your script tag at the beginning of the document if you can, or hack it by not using onclick handlers directly but using js itself to attach the event handlers. Workdpress might be messing with the way the DOM and scripts load, so you can NOT use onlick or onchange directly and instead use that document.ready to just attach the handlers.

Comment: @Nikki9696 Yes, very limited. I moved the script tags to the top of the page and still nothing. I'm still just weirded out that it will work sometimes, but not others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

Wordpress was adding random

tags, and they invaded the script code, which the javascript/jquery didn't like.

Thanks for everybody's help!

Answer (score 1):

Add some null checks and stuff, as I got an error while messing around and it expected a value.

I removed a bad char after this line and took functions out of doc ready

```
document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("540.00"); '
```

```js
function grabText() {
  var x = document.getElementById("enteredText").value;
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = x;
  getTotal();
}

var changeFontStyle = function (font) {
          document.getElementById(
                "text").style.fontFamily
                        = font.value;
};

var changeColorStyle = function (color) {
    document.getElementById("text").style.color = color.value;
};

function countChars(obj){
    var maxLength = 20;
    var strLength = obj.value.length + 1;
    var charRemain = (maxLength - strLength);
    document.getElementById("hiddenChars").value = strLength;
    if(charRemain < 0){
        document.getElementById("remainingChars").innerHTML = '<span style="color: red;">You have exceeded the limit of '+maxLength+' characters</span>';
    }else{
        document.getElementById("remainingChars").innerHTML = charRemain+' characters remaining';
    }
};

function getTotal() {
  var z = document.getElementById("hiddenChars").value;
  var x = document.getElementById("selectedSize").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("selectedMount").value;
  var d = document.getElementById("selectedDimmer").value;
if(x != "select" && z === "") {
  document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' Please enter custom text.';
  document.getElementById("price").value = NULL;
  document.getElementById("submitValues").disabled = true;
}
if(x === "20" && z === "1") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $180';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("180.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "1") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $263';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("263.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "1") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $306';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("306.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "1") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $330';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("330.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "1") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $380';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("380.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "2") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $200';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("200.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "2") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $286';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("286.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "2") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $332';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("332.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "2") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $360';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("360.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "2") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $410';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("410.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "3") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $220';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("220.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "3") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $309';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("309.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "3") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $358';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("358.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "3") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $480';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("480.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "3") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $440';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("440.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "4") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $240';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("240.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "4") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $332';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("332.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "4") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $384';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("384.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "4") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $580';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("580.00");
 }   
if(x === "60" && z === "4") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $470';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("470.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "5") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $260';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("260.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "5") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $355';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("355.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "5") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $410';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("410.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "5") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $458';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("458.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "5") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $500';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("500.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "6") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $280';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("280.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "6") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $378';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("378.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "6") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $436';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("436.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "6") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $558';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("558.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "6") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $530';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("530.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "7") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $300';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("300.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "7") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $401';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("401.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "7") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $462';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("462.00");
 }  
if(x === "50" && z === "7") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $436';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("436.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "7") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $560';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("560.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "8") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $320';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("320.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "8") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $424';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("424.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "8") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $488';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("488.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "8") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $536';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("536.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "8") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $590';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("590.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "9") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $340';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("340.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "9") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $447';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("447.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "9") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $514';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("514.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "9") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $636';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("636.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "9") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $620';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("620.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "10") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $360';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("360.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "10") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $470';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("470.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "10") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $540';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("540.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "10") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $510';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("510.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "10") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $650';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("650.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "11") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $380';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("380.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "11") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $493';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("493.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "11") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $566';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("566.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "11") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $610';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("610.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "11") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $680';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("680.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "12") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $400';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("400.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "12") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $516';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("516.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "12") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $592';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("592.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "12") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $710';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("710.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "12") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $710';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("710.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "13") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $420';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("420.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "13") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $539';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("539.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "13") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $618';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("618.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "13") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $570';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("570.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "13") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $740';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("740.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "14") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $440';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("440.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "14") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $562';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("562.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "14") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $644';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("644.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "14") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $670';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("670.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "14") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $770';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("770.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "15") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $460';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("460.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "15") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $585';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("585.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "15") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $670';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("670.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "15") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $770';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("770.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "15") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $800';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("800.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "16") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $480';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("480.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "16") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $608';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("608.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "16") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $696';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("696.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "16") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $800';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("800.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "16") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $830';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("830.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "17") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $500';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("500.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "17") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $631';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("631.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "17") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $722';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("722.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "17") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $800';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("800.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "17") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $860';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("860.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "18") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $520';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("520.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "18") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $654';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("654.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "18") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $748';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("748.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "18") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $800';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("800.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "18") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $890';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("890.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "19") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $540';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("540.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "19") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $677';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("677.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "19") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $774';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("774.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "19") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $800';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("800.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "19") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $920';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("920.00");
 }
if(x === "20" && z === "20") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $560';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("560.00");
 }
if(x === "30" && z === "20") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $700';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("800.00");
 }
if(x === "40" && z === "20") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $800';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("800.00");
 }
if(x === "50" && z === "20") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $800';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("800.00");
 }
if(x === "60" && z === "20") {
   document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = ' $950';
   document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat("950.00");
 }
if(d === "yes") {
 var p = document.getElementById("price").value;
 console.log(p);
 var n = parseFloat("50.00");
 console.log(n);
 t = +p + +n;
 console.log(t);
 document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = " $" + t;
 }
};

function getOption() { 
    selectElement = document.querySelector('#selectedFont');                     
    output = selectElement.value; 
    document.querySelector('.output').textContent = output;
getTotal();
}; 
function getSizeOption() { 
    selectElement = document.querySelector('#selectedSize');                  
    outputSize = selectElement.value;   
    document.querySelector('.outputSize').textContent = outputSize;     
    getTotal(); 
};
function getMountOption() { 
    selectElement = document.querySelector('#selectedMount');                      
    outputMount = selectElement.value;  
    document.querySelector('.outputMount').textContent = outputMount;   
    getTotal();
};  
function getPowerWireOption() { 
    selectElement = document.querySelector('#selectedPowerWire');                   
    outputPowerWire = selectElement.value;
    document.querySelector('.outputPowerWire').textContent = outputPowerWire;   
    getTotal();
}; 
function getBackingOption() { 
    selectElement = document.querySelector('#selectedBacking');                
    outputBacking = selectElement.value;  
    document.querySelector('.outputBacking').textContent = outputBacking; 
    getTotal();
};
function getColorOption() { 
    selectElement = document.querySelector('#selectedColor'); 
    outputColor = selectElement.value; 
    document.querySelector('.outputColor').textContent = outputColor; 
getTotal();
};
```

```css
 .column {
float: left;
width: 50%;
padding: 10px;
}
/* Clear floats after the columns *
.row:after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
}
/* Container holding the image and the text */
.container {
position: relative;
}
/* Centered text */
.centered {
text-shadow: 0 0 2px, 0 0 5px, 0 0 50px, 0 0 10px, 0 0 60px, 0 0 60px;
position: absolute;
top: 30%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>DESIGN YOUR OWN VIBE</h1>
<h3>Type in your message, choose font, and color.</h3>
<div class="column">
<div class="container">
<img style="box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black;" src="https://omgneonsigns.com/wp-content/plugins/neon-designer-1.5.4/includes/image/background1.jpg" />
<div class="centered">
<p id="text" style="font-size: 45px; padding-right: 10px;"></p>
</div>
</div>
<h1>Total Cost:<span id="outputCost" style="font-size: 25px; padding-right: 10px;"></span></h1>
</div>
<div class="column" style="box-shadow: 5px 2px 55px gray;">
<h3>INPUT TEXT</h3>
<form action="/cart/?add-to-cart=5825" method="post" name="contentForm">
<p id="remainingChars"></p>
<textarea id="enteredText" style="height: 15px;" name="enteredText" onkeyup="grabText()" onkeydown="countChars(this)" placeholder="Your Text..."></textarea>
<input id="hiddenText" name="hiddenText" type="hidden" value=""></input>
<h3>CHOOSE FONT</h3>
<select name="chosenFont" onchange="changeFontStyle(this)">
<option value="select">-SELECT-</option>
<option style="font-family: 'roboto';" value="roboto">Roboto</option>
<option style="font-family: 'arial';" value="arial">Arial</option>
<option style="font-family: 'times new roman';" value="times new roman">Times New Roman</option>
<option style="font-family: 'comic sans ms';" value="comic sans ms">Comic Sans MS</option>
<option style="font-family: 'clarendon-fortune-bold';" value="clarendon fortune bold">Clarendon Fortune</option>
<option style="font-family: 'copperplate';" value="copperplate">Copperplate</option>
<option style="font-family: 'ribbon-condensed';" value="ribbon condensed">Ribbon Condensed</option>
</select>
<input id="hiddenFont" name="hiddenFont" type="hidden" value=""></input>
<h3>CHOOSE COLOR</h3>
<select id="selectedColor" name="chosenColor" onchange="changeColorStyle(this)">
<option value="select">-SELECT-</option>
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
<option value="green">Green</option>
<option value="orange">Orange</option>
<option value="pink">Pink</option>
<option value="white">White</option>
<option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
<option value="#dce6ef">Ice Blue</option>
</select>
<input id="hiddenColor" name="hiddenColor" type="hidden" value="" />
<h3>CHOOSE SIZE</h3>
<select id="selectedSize" name="chosenSize" onchange="getTotal();">
<option value="select">-SELECT-</option>
<option value="20">20"</option>
<option value="30">30"</option>
<option value="40">40"</option>
<option value="50">50"</option>
<option value="60">60"</option>
</select>
<input id="hiddenSize" name="hiddenSize" type="hidden" value="" />
<h3>CHOOSE POWER WIRE</h3>
Power wire on back is recommended for professional installation by an electrician. Power wire on front is recommended for residential installation.
<select id="selectedPowerWire" name="chosenPower" onchange="getTotal();">
<option value="select">-SELECT-</option>
<option value="front">Power Wire In FRONT</option>
<option value="back">Power Wire In BACK</option>
</select>
<input id="hiddenPowerWire" name="hiddenPowerWire" type="hidden" value="" />
<h3>CHOOSE MOUNT</h3>
Wall mount is recommended for general installations. Hanging is recommended for window display.
<select id="selectedMount" name="chosenMount" onchange="getTotal();">
<option value="select">-SELECT-</option>
<option value="wall mount">Wall Mount</option>
<option value="hanging">Hanging</option>
<option value="stand">Stand</option>
</select>
<input id="hiddenMount" name="hiddenMount" type="hidden" value="" />
<h3>CHOOSE BACKING</h3>
<select id="selectedBacking" name="chosenBacking" onchange="getTotal();">
<option value="select">-SELECT-</option>
<option value="cut to shape">Cut To Shape</option>
<option value="whole board">Whole Board</option>
</select>
<input id="hiddenBacking" name="hiddenBacking" type="hidden" value="" />
<h3>DIMMER?</h3>
<select id="selectedDimmer" name="chosenDimmer" onchange="getTotal();">
<option value="select">-SELECT-</option>
<option value="yes">Yes ($50.00)</option>
<option value="no">No</option>
</select>
<input id="hiddenDimmer" name="hiddenDimmer" type="hidden" value="" />
<input id="price" name="price" type="hidden" value="" />
<input id="hiddenChars" name="hiddenChars" type="hidden" value="" />
<input type="submit" id="submitValues" value="Add To Cart" />
</form></div>
```